# Lock-free zero-copy triple buffer

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, lock-free

In a producer-consumer scenario sometimes we have to deal with the producer being much faster than consumer. The data loss is unavoidable, and we are OK with it, as long as the consumer always has the most recent data.

The answer is triple buffering. Endow the system with three buffers, which assume the roles of being `presented`, `ready`, and `inprogress`, and let them change their roles according to the rules:

- Once the `presented` buffer is completely presented, swap roles with `ready`.
- Once the `inprogress` buffer is completely produced, swap roles with `ready`.

It is possible (unlikely but still possible) for producer to fall behind. Consumer must detect such situation, and not present a stale buffer. In other words, the `presented/ready` swap shall happen only if `ready` has been updated since the last swap.

I am particularly not proud with the `stale` flag being a part of termination flow.

PS: The fine-grain controls such as `start` and `stop` methods are intentionally not designed in.

Meanwhile, **triple-buffer.h**

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

template<typename buffer, void produce(buffer *), void consume(buffer *)>
class triple_buffer {
    std::atomic<buffer *> present;
    std::atomic<buffer *> ready;
    std::atomic<buffer *> inprogress;

    std::atomic<bool> stop;
    std::atomic_flag stale;

    std::thread consumer_thread;
    std::thread producer_thread;

    void producer()
    {
        while (!stop) {
            produce(inprogress.load());
            inprogress = ready.exchange(inprogress);
            stale.clear();
        }
    }

    void consumer()
    {
        while (!stop) {
            consume(present.load());
            while (stale.test_and_set())
                ;
            present = ready.exchange(present);
        }
    }

public:
    triple_buffer() = delete;
    triple_buffer(triple_buffer& other) = delete;
    triple_buffer(triple_buffer&& other) = delete;
    triple_buffer& operator=(triple_buffer& other) = delete;

    triple_buffer(buffer bufs[3])
        : present(&bufs[0])
        , ready(&bufs[1])
        , inprogress(&bufs[2])
    {
        stop.store(false);
        stale.test_and_set();

        produce(present);

        consumer_thread = std::move(std::thread([this] { consumer(); }));
        producer_thread = std::move(std::thread([this] { producer(); }));
    }

    ~triple_buffer()
    {
        stop.store(true);
        producer_thread.join();

        stale.clear();
        consumer_thread.join();
    }
};
```

and a short **demo.cpp**

```
#include "triple-buffer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

struct buffer {
    int id;
    int value;
};      

void produce(buffer * buf)
{               
    static int value = 0;
    buf->value = value++;
}   

void consume(buffer * buf)
{   
    std::cout << buf->id << ": " << buf->value << '\n';
}   

int main()
{
    buffer bufs[3] { {0}, {1}, {2} };
    triple_buffer<buffer, produce, consume> tb(bufs);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
}
```

Comment: You might be interested in [my attempt at a similar problem](/q/259929/75307). I wrote it independently, then saw this question in the "related" list.

Comment: @vnp I didn't post as an answer as you specifically request C++11, but in C++20 you an use `atomic<bool> stale` to do away with the spinlock, e.g. in the consumer: `stale.wait(true); stale.store(true)` and in the producer: `stale.store(false); stale.notify_one()`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The concurrency looks bug-free to me, which is rare!

Some nits on C++ idioms:

It is *extremely* unusual to take a function pointer as a template parameter. This drastically limits the reusability of your class template. A more traditional, "STL-ish" interface would be

```
template<class Buffer, class Produce, class Consume>
class triple_buffer {
    explicit triple_buffer(Buffer bufs[3]);
    explicit triple_buffer(Buffer bufs[3], Produce produce, Consume consume);
    // ...
};
```

Or, since `produce` and `consume` are used only inside the constructor — it immediately wraps them up in lambdas and passes them off to `std::thread` — you don't even need them to be template parameters of the whole class. They can be template parameters of the *constructor itself*. Something like this:

```
template<class Buffer>
class triple_buffer {
    template<class P, class C>
    explicit triple_buffer(Buffer bufs[3], P produce, C consume) {
        // ...
        produce(present_.load());
        producer_thread_ = std::thread([&, produce]() {
            while (!stop_.load()) {
                produce(inprogress_.load());
                inprogress_ = ready_.exchange(inprogress_);
                stale_.store(false);
            }
        });
        // ...
    }
};
```

(In C++14 you can capture `produce` as `[&, produce = std::move(produce)]` to avoid making a copy of it.)

Notice the `CamelCase` template parameter names.

I also recommend sigilling the names of your member variables — `ready_` rather than `ready`, and so on. (Some coding style guides prefer `m_ready` or `d_ready`. No big deal.)

These two naming conventions, together, will help to alleviate some of your confusingly similar naming. Right now you've got a template parameter named `produce` and a member function named `producer` (and your test harness has a global function named `produce`). Of course, I just "fixed" that naming issue by getting rid of the `producer` member function altogether!

---

You use both `atomic<bool> stop` and `atomic_flag stale`. There's no significant difference between `atomic<bool>` and `atomic_flag`; you should pick one and stick to it. I recommend `atomic<bool>` because it's one fewer thing for your coworkers to look up on cppreference.

---

```
inprogress = ready.exchange(inprogress);
```

This line is correct, but I *really strongly* encourage you to rewrite it as two lines anyway. "One side-effect per source line" is a good rule of thumb for concurrent code. And there really are two side-effects happening here.

```
Buffer *p = ready.exchange(inprogress);
inprogress.store(p);
```

Splitting it up this way makes it clear what's going on — in particular that the swap is *not* being effected atomically — and incidentally makes the code easier to stress-test (by adding instrumentation between each pair of lines) and debug (because now it's possible to pause the debugger between the two side-effects).

---

```
while (stale.test_and_set())
```

If you switch to consistently using `atomic<bool>`, this line would become

```
while (stale.exchange(true))
```

---

```
consumer_thread = std::move(std::thread([this] { consumer(); }));
```

This line is overengineered. You don't need to `std::move` a prvalue. And personally, I'd capture `[&]` unless I had a special reason not to. So:

```
consumer_thread = std::thread([&]{ consumer(); });
```

---

Stylistically, I wonder why `triple_buffer` takes a pointer to an array of three `Buffer` objects, as opposed to either

- taking three pointers to `Buffer` objects (which then needn't be adjacent in memory), or
- giving `triple_buffer` three member variables of type `Buffer`.

Comment: Thanks for the review. I already lost all hopes. And very good points indeed.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>         while (stale.test_and_set())
>             ;
> ```

This spinlock might be appropriate given that the producer is usually faster than the consumer.

If the consumer usually has to wait for the producer, then this is just an expensive space-heater, and we should consider waiting on a condition variable instead (but only enter that slow path if we didn't find it ready using the normal, fast, method).

Comment: Right. The very first sentence of a scenario description reads _the producer being much faster than consumer_.

Comment: Slightly re-worded.